Can you insert images/pdfs and tables into buttons on SharePoint mailto function
I have a sharepoint page I used that has a button which when you click it outputs a mailto function and then gives some text in the body of the email.
Is it possible to set it up so that when it opens outlook with an email the email is populated with an image and a table which can have some prefilled information?
The button is used to request and update form and I would like the mailto to include a filled out example (an image) and a table with prefilled information to make it easier to request changes.

Unfortunately, it is not possible to pass the HTML tables, images, etc. in email body while using mailto link. It takes only string/text value.
Check this official documentation for more information: Creating hyperlinks
Also, check this thread for more explanation: mailto link with HTML body.
Similar threads:

Is there any way to pass html content while triggering mailto: option?
How do I pass HTML table inside mailto in anchor tag?

